# CG Gradient Crash

Tags: ios, exception, gradient

wondering if someone could help me, but at the same time hopefully I can help someone else too...

I have this problem with a CG Gradient that runs in the simulator but crashes on a device. I have searched and read the "CG Gradient runs on simulator, but not on iPhone" thread and I think its a similar problem, i.e due to me using ARC and it releasing the CGFloat too early, but I can't quite get my head around how to implement the suggested fixes in relation to my code. (Please see the code at the bottom)

So I would be grateful if someone could help me with that part??

Anyway, the crash is so bad that it seems to continue to run the app on device in a really odd state, I can delete the app on the device and try to run it again with the offending code commented out, but it still causes a crash. No matter what I did it would not allow the app to run on the device again. Turns out that after some hours of scratching my head, that I needed to reset the iPad device I was attempting to deploy to as it was still holding onto the provisioning profile despite being closed / deleted from the device.

Hopefully, that makes some sense and can help someone too.

Thanks

```
CGFloat colors [] = { 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0
};    

CGFloat colors2 [] = { 
    190.00/255.00, 211.00/255.00, 60.00/255.00, 1.0, 
    138.00/255.00, 153.00/255.00, 43.00/255.00, 1.0
};

CGFloat colors3 [] = { 
    159.00/255.00, 164.00/255.00, 39.00/255.00, 1.0,
    110.00/255.00, 120.00/255.00, 27.00/255.00, 1.0 

};


CGColorSpaceRef baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGGradientRef gradient;
if (which_state==@"1") {
    gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, colors2, NULL, 2);
    NSLog(@"which state has changed");
} else if (which_state==@"2"){
    gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, colors3, NULL, 2);
} else if (which_state==@"3"){
    gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, colors3, NULL, 2);
} else if (which_state==@"0"){
    gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, colors, NULL, 2);
}


CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace), baseSpace = NULL;


CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, (width/4*0)+5, 0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, (width/4*0)+30, self.frame.size.height-3);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, (width/4*1)+30, self.frame.size.height-3);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, (width/4*1)+5, 0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, (width/4*0)+5, 0);
CGContextClip(context);

CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
CGGradientRelease(gradient), gradient = NULL;

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

Comment: Please post the details of the crash, or nobody will be able to help you. If the app continues to run, this is not a crash.

Comment: thanks for replying, I dont have the crash details to hand, but will post it asap. From memory it highlights it in the app delegate section, but also indicates the line with CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said how the app is crashing, but this looks wrong:

```
CGGradientRef gradient; 
if (which_state==@"1")
...
```

You are comparing strings using `==`, and you should be using `if ([which_state isEqualToString:@"1"])`. `==` Checks for pointer equality, not string equality. From the look of your code it might be better to use an enum, but that's a side issue.

If your code goes through that set of if statements without hitting anything (since `==` may not give you a match) then you have an uninitialized `CGGradientRef`, which you later on attempt to draw and release. This would cause a crash.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying and sorry for not having the details of the crash, I will update this asap, I am aware that I should probably be using the isEqual approach, but I don't think this is the problem due to it running ok in the simulator and not even starting on the device... I think this is due to ARC releasing the CGFloat colors etc. too early and I'm wondering is there a way to ensure this is retained...

Comment: @Deadfrog: The incorrect equality check probably *is* related to the crash, as you don't have an unconditional `else` and thus you will never even create a gradient. Your `gradient` variable will contain a garbage pointer which might get dereferenced and the stuff at that random location is then interpreted as a gradient.

Comment: ok, thanks... I'll try altering that and post back results. Can I ask why this would only create a problem on the device though and not on the simulator? It doesnt even open on the device but works perfectly as expected in the simulator?

Comment: @Deadfrog ARC has nothing to do with your CGFloat arrays, these are scalar variables and memory management is not relevant to them.

Comment: Memory is handled differently on the device and on the simulator. It could be that @"1" on the simulator is given the same pointer address as your original value, but this doesn't take place on the device.

Comment: Right, that makes sense if memory is handled differently between the two I guess... Thanks for everyones comments, they are appreciated, will post back when I have had a chance to experiment with deploying it to the device again...

Comment: Ok, so I have had a chance to implement the isEqualToString and it still crashed, but both of your suggestions certainly put me onto the right track... It was due to the init method not setting the string, so the pointer was actually NULL and therefor never created the gradient... I have placed a or statement for the NULL condition. Thanks to both jrturton and DarkDust, it now deploys successfully to the device...